# Insert result in DB using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I new in laravel framework, I want to pass the result of the calculation from water.blade.php TO controller because I want to insert this result on database

[water.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsEci.png)

[PageController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AJoS.png)

Comment: the result of what calculation, exactly? It's unclear, from what you've posted. (And...please don't post _pictures_ of your code. Code is text. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for why it's unhelpful.)

Comment: Looks like you are retrieving data to show, but that method actually inserts data, and apparently its not working as you are not actually passing any values.  But I guess you need to edit your question to clarify this - we should not guess your intention.

Comment: please share your code here, not links of your files.

Answer (score 0):

But wich way you want to pass this result?

If you want with post, you can make a form, and a submit button.

in the view..

```
<form action="{{route('myRouteToPost')}}">
<!-- Insert your code here -->
</form>
```

In the routes/web.php you must define this route:

```
Route::post('nameOftheController@methodOfTheController')->name('myRouteToPost')
```

And when someone submit the form, the method of the controller you has specificated will recive on $request.